# cannot make response.redirect work

Tags: c#, button, submit, response.redirect

i have this simple code and what i want is to check if the customer type if a commercial customer. if not, error will appear. if yes, it will be directed to the other page. am i missing something here?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ("Customer Type" != "Commercial Customer")
        {
            lblerror.Text = "For commercial customers only";
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Redirect("CreditRequestRegistration.aspx");
        }

    }
```

Here is my aspx code:

```
<ItemTemplate>  
              <table id="tblcustomerprofile" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
                   <tr>
                        <%--<td style="width:100px">
                            ID:
                        </td>
                        <td style="width:250px">
                            <strong><%# Eval("ID")%></strong>
                        </td>--%>
                   <tr>
                        <td class="style1" style="border-style:ridge; border-width:thick; border-color:White;  background-color:#FF3300; font-size:small; color:White">
                            Username:
                        </td>
                        <td class="style2" style ="border-style:ridge; border-width:thin">
                            <strong><%# Eval("Username")%></strong>
                        </td>
                        <tr>
                        <td class="style3" style="border-style:ridge; border-width:thick; border-color:White;  background-color:#FF3300; font-size:small; color:White">
                            FirstName:
                        </td>
                        <td class="style4" style="border-style:ridge; border-width:thin">
                            <strong><%# Eval("Firstname")%></strong>
                        </td>
                        <tr>
                        <td class="style20" 
                                style="border-style:ridge; border-width:thick; border-color:White;  background-color:#FF3300; font-size:small; color:White">
                            LastName:
                        </td>
                        <td class="style21" style="border-style:ridge; border-width:thin">
                            <strong><%# Eval("Lastname")%></strong>
                        </td>                            
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style9" style="border-style:ridge; border-width:thick; border-color:White;  background-color:#FF3300; font-size:small; color:White">
                            Email Address:
                        </td>
                        <td class="style10" style="border-style:ridge; border-width:thin">
                            <strong><%# Eval("Email")%></strong>
                        </td>
                        <tr>
                        <td class="style11" style="border-style:ridge; border-width:thick; border-color:White;  background-color:#FF3300; font-size:small; color:White">
                            Password:
                        </td>
                        <td class="style12" style="border-style:ridge; border-width:thin">
                            <strong><%# Eval("Password")%></strong>
                        </td>                                                        
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style13" style="border-style:ridge; border-width:thick; border-color:White;  background-color:#FF3300; font-size:small; color:White">
                            Customer Type:
                        </td>
                        <td class="style14" style="border-style:ridge; border-width:thin">
                            <strong><%# Eval("CustomerType")%></strong>
                        </td>                                                        
                    </tr>                        
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style15" style="border-style:ridge; border-width:thick; border-color:White;  background-color:#FF3300; font-size:small; color:White">
                            Delivery Address:
                        </td>
                        <td class="style19" style="border-style:ridge; border-width:thin">
                            <strong><%# Eval("DeliveryAddress") %></strong>
                        </td>
                        <tr>
                        <td class="style15" style="border-style:ridge; border-width:thick; border-color:White;  background-color:#FF3300; font-size:small; color:White">
                            Zip Code:
                        </td>
                        <td class="style19" style="border-style:ridge; border-width:thin">
                            <strong><%# Eval("Zip")%></strong>
                        </td>                                                                                  
                    </tr>
                        <tr>                            
                        <td class="style17" style=" border-style:ridge; border-width:thick; border-color:White;  background-color:#FF3300; font-size:small; color:White">
                            Contact Number:
                        </td>
                        <td class="style18" style="border-style:ridge; border-width:thin">
                            <strong><%# Eval("ContactNumber")%></strong>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>


                    <asp:LinkButton ID="EditButton" ForeColor="Blue"
                                    Text="Update Profile"
                                    CommandName="Edit"
                                    RunAt="server"/>
                      &nbsp;

            </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: You are comparing 2 strings which are obviously not equal. How will else part get executed ?

Comment: how can i compare those if they are in gridview? Customertype is the header and Commercial Customer is in data field

Comment: You loop through the formview control using a foreach and compare the text in the 'Customer type' column.

Comment: can you give me an example? i would really really appreciate it @Partha

Comment: This will give you some idea: http://codeverge.com/asp.net.web-forms/loop-through-all-controls-in-formview-editi/423878

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83040/discussion-between-partha-and-paolo-duhaylungsod).

Comment: thanks @Partha. i have googled for some answer. can i use something like formview.findcontrol?